# How to turn a DIP switch into an array of logical values

Tags: digital-logic, resistors, switches, logic-level, dip

Is there a better way to turn a open/closed switch into a logical value (capable or sinking or sourcing current) other than:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvT3hs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm playing with 8 bit DIP switches and I was wondering if there was something better than 8 resistors.

Note: I could swap the positions of the switch and resistor, but I think this arrangement is better as the voltage-required-to-register-a-high is usually further beneath Vcc than the voltage-required-to-register-a-low is above GND, allowing a larger resistor and therefore less leakage.

Comment: What about ladder of 8 resistors?

Comment: Nice ASCII art, but there's a schematic editor built into the question editor.  Edit your question and press CTRL+M to open the schematic editor.

Comment: See how the logical gates are implemented using MOSFETS. You'll get the idea.

Comment: You could use it as input to a shift register if you're really short on input pins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many microcontrollers contain pull-up resistors internally (even Arduino). You often have to configure your pins to activate them (e.g. [INPUT_PULLUP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PinMode) for Arduino), and once it is done you can simply connect your DIP switch to the pin and the ground. Besides the obvious advantage of cutting your BOM down, you can be sure R will have the right value for your microcontroller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhqrYM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>